# Slf4j is not showing the logs on my local server

Tags: spring-boot, logging, slf4j, gradlew

Hello I'm using spring boot and I am not able to see the logs I print in my IDE or in my local environment, these are my dependencies:

```
testCompileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.16.41
+--- software.amazon.awssdk:kms:2.16.41
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-json-protocol:2.16.41
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:2.16.41
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2 -> 1.0.4
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 -> 2.0.9
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2 -> 1.0.4
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 -> 2.0.9
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.3
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.3 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.3 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.3 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.3
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2 -> 1.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 -> 2.0.9
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- software.amazon.eventstream:eventstream:1.0.1
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 -> 2.0.9
|    |    |    \--- software.amazon.eventstream:eventstream:1.0.1
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:2.16.41
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    \--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    \--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
+--- software.amazon.awssdk:ssm:2.16.41
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-json-protocol:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    \--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
\--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.+ -> 3.12.4
     +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.11.13 -> 1.14.10
     +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.11.13 -> 1.14.10
     \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:3.2

testCompileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'test'. (n)
No dependencies

+--- software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.16.41+--- software.amazon.awssdk:kms:2.16.41
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-json-protocol:2.16.41spath > Resolve dependencies of :detachedConfiguration92
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:2.16.41
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2 -> 1.0.4
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 -> 2.0.9
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2 -> 1.0.4
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 -> 2.0.9
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.3
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.3 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.3 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.15.3 (c)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.15.3
|    |    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2 -> 1.0.4
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 -> 2.0.9
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- software.amazon.eventstream:eventstream:1.0.1
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 -> 2.0.9
|    |    |    \--- software.amazon.eventstream:eventstream:1.0.1
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:2.16.41
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    |    \--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.12.1 -> 2.15.3 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client:2.16.41
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    |    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.13 -> 4.4.16
|    |    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
|    |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11 -> 1.16.0
|    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.11 -> 4.4.16
|    \--- software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:2.16.41
|         +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|         +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|         +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|         +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|         +--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.61.Final -> 4.1.104.Final
|         |         +--- io.netty:netty-resolver:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |         +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |         +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |         +--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:4.1.104.Final
|         |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.104.Final
|         |         |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |         |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |         \--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         +--- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:4.1.61.Final -> 4.1.104.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.104.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |    \--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         +--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.1.61.Final -> 4.1.104.Final (*)
|         +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.61.Final -> 4.1.104.Final (*)
|         +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.61.Final -> 4.1.104.Final
|         +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.61.Final -> 4.1.104.Final (*)
|         +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.61.Final -> 4.1.104.Final (*)
|         +--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:4.1.61.Final -> 4.1.104.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.104.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |    \--- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:4.1.104.Final
|         |         +--- io.netty:netty-common:4.1.104.Final
|         |         +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |         +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |         \--- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:4.1.104.Final (*)
|         +--- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams-http:2.0.4
|         |    +--- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:2.0.4
|         |    |    +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.1.43.Final -> 4.1.104.Final (*)
|         |    |    \--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.3 -> 1.0.4
|         |    \--- io.netty:netty-codec-http:4.1.43.Final -> 4.1.104.Final (*)
|         +--- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:1.0.2 -> 1.0.4
|         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.28 -> 2.0.9
+--- software.amazon.awssdk:ssm:2.16.41
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-json-protocol:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:2.16.41
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:2.16.41 (*)
|    +--- software.amazon.awssdk:metrics-spi:2.16.41 (*)
```

It seems like Slf4j is included in lombook, the next is my logback.xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %replace(%msg){'\n','&#xd;'} %replace(%exception){'\n','&#xd;'} %nopexception %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

But I am not getting any file or log printed on my IDE, even though they are printed in the server where the app is deployed, any ideas what am I missing? thanks!